# Tree or not (Haskell type understanding)

Tags: haskell, types, binary-tree, graph-theory

In "A Gentle Introduction to Haskell" we have such declaration of Tree's type:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch (Tree a) (Tree a)
     deriving (Eq,Ord,Show,Read)
```

Let's to make some values of this type:

```
a1 = Leaf 1
a2 = Leaf 2
a3 = Leaf 3
a4 = a1 `Branch` a2
a5 = a2 `Branch` a3
a6 = a4 `Branch` a5
```

in ghci:

```
*Main> :t a6
a6 :: Tree Integer
```

But `a6` is not Tree at all, see:

```
      a6
     / \
   a4   a5
  / \  /  \
a1   a2    a3
```

There is a cycle in this graph!
What is wrong? Is type definition of Tree correct?
Or maybe, I can't catch some mistake in understanding of this example...

Comment: It is not a tree ora non-tree because a picture on a piece of paper insinuates so. Why do you think you can use a2 just once in the picture? If you change your program such that all your nodes contain the number 42, would you draw 42 once or 4 times? There's no substantial difference between built-in and user-defined data types, so 42 is on equal standing with Leaf 42. In order to demonstrate that this is not a tree, you need to produce *a Haskell program* that detects this "cycle". And you simply can't. The semantics of Haskell doesn't allow such a program to exist.

Comment: thanks a lot, guys! I can see now what was my misunderstanding!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is that conceptually, `a2` "is" a `Tree a`, not a reference to a `Tree a`. In that sense, `a6` really looks like

```
          a6
       /      \
     a4        a5
    /   \    /    \
  a1   a2   a2    a3
```

that is, there are two "copies" of `a2` in the tree.

Practically speaking, since all the values are immutable, the implementation can use the same memory to represent both the right child of `a4` and the left child of `a5`, but the two nodes remain distinct at the level of abstraction represented by the `Tree a` type.

In order to actually have a cycle, there needs to be some notion of being able to reach both `a4` and `a5` from `a2`, and this type doesn't provide a representation for any such child-to-parent links, which makes it impossible to tell if `a4`'s left child and `a5`'s right child are the *same* node, or two different nodes that look exactly alike. For this data type, the distinction simply does not exist.

Answer (score 5):

We should distinguish between the *value* of an expression, and its memory representation.

For instance, both these expressions have the same *value*:

```
e1 = ("Hello", "Hello")
e2 = let s = "Hello" in (s, s)
```

Indeed, in Haskell there is no way to distinguish between the results of the evaluation of the expressions above. They are semantically equivalent.

A Haskell implementation (e.g. GHC) is free to represent those values in memory in any way that does not break the semantics. For instance:

1. It might store the string `"Hello"` twice in memory, and then use a pair of pointers `(p1, p2)`.
2. It might store the string `"Hello"` once in memory, and then use a pair of pointers `(p, p)`.

Note that both representations could, in theory, be used for any one of the expressions `e1,e2` above. In practice, GHC will use the former for `e2` and the latter for `e1`, but that's not important.

In your trees, the same issue arises. The value of your `a6` is a tree. GHC probably represents that tree as a non-tree DAG (i.e. a DAG which, if transformed into an undirected graph, has a cycle), but it does not matter, it's only an implementation detail. The important aspect is that such representation respects the semantics of a tree.

One might then wonder why a DAG representation is sound if the value is a tree. This holds because in Haskell we can not compare the underlying "references" `p` used by GHC. If we had a function `comparePtr :: a -> a -> Bool` which compares such references we could distinguish between `e1` and `e2` by using `comparePtr (fst e) (snd e)` for `e` between `e1`,`e2`. That would horribly break the soundness of the implementation. In Haskell we do not have that, though.

(Well, technically, there is an `unsafe` function doing that, but `unsafe` functions should never be used in "normal" code. We usually pretend those do not exist.)

Comment: The A in DAG is "acyclic" - you don't mean it's a DAG with a cycle, but rather a DAG wherein one node has two parents. Its memory representation is probably not a tree, but its semantic value is of course still a tree, as you say. At any rate neither of them has a cycle.

Comment: @amalloy Good point. I mean that the DAG, when transformed into an _undirected_ graph, has a cycle. I used the term "cycle" since the OP did that in the question for the same notion, so to be more understandable to the OP. I'll add more detail.